# Error en laravel al hacer post Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy realizando un CRUD sencillo en laravel 5.5 junto con laravel colective pero simplemmnete no me manda el post de hecho ni reconoce el request:

Estan son mis rutas

```
 Route::get('/admin/products/{id}/edit', 'ProductController@edit')->name('EditarRegistro');//Formulario de Edicion // EL NAME ES PARA laravel colective
Route::post('/admin/products/{id}', 'ProductController@update')->name('productos.update'); //Formulario Actualizar
```

Este es mi controlador utilizando edit y update

```
public function edit($id)//este id permitira buscar el id del producto seleccionado y una vez encontrado se pasara a la vista
{

    $BuscarProducto = Producto::find($id);
    $buscarcategoria = Categoria::find($BuscarProducto->category_id);


    return view('admin.products.edit')->with('RenombradoBuscarVista', $BuscarProducto)->with('RenombradoCategoriaVista', $buscarcategoria);

}


public function update(Request $request, $id){

    //return view();  // resgistart un nuevo producto a la base de datos
    dd($request);

    $Categoria = Categoria::find($id);
    $Categoria->name = $request->namec;  //el namec es el nombre dl input
    $Categoria->save();   // para guardar el registro
    $idCategoria = $Categoria->id; //sacar el ultimo id de la insersion de categoria

    $Producto = Producto::find($idCategoria );
    $Producto->name = $request->input('name');
    $Producto->description = $request->input('description');
    $Producto->long_description = $request->descripcionl;
    $Producto->price = $request->input('price');
    $Producto->category_id = $idCategoria;
    $Producto->save(); //insert
    $idProducto = $Producto->id;


    $Imagen = ProductImage::find($idProducto);
    $Imagen->product_id = $idProducto;
    $Imagen->save();  

    return redirect('/admin/products');

}
```

y aqui esta mi vista como mencione utlizo laravel colective

```
{!!Form::model($RenombradoBuscarVista, ['method' => 'PUT', 'action' => ['ProductController@update',$RenombradoBuscarVista->id]]) !!}
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6>
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label">Nombre del producto</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$RenombradoBuscarVista->name}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Categoria</label>  
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="namec" value="{{$RenombradoCategoriaVista->name}}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                    <label class="control-label">Descripcion</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="{{$RenombradoBuscarVista->description}}">
        </div>




                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                    <label class="control-label">Precio del Producto</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" value="{{$RenombradoBuscarVista->price}}">
        </div>



        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Descripcion extensa del producto"  name="descripcionl" >{{$RenombradoBuscarVista->long_description}}</textarea>

        {!!Form::submit('Guardar cambios',array('class' => 'btn btn-primary'))!!}

        <a href="{{ url('/admin/products')}}" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>





{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Cabe mencionar que si me manda la vista, el error aparece cuando doy clic en el boton de actualizar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás utilizando el verbo PUT en el formulario:

```
{!!Form::model($RenombradoBuscarVista, ['method' => 'PUT', 'action' => ['ProductController@update',$RenombradoBuscarVista->id]]) !!}
```

Pero en la ruta estás esperando un POST:

```
Route::post('/admin/products/{id}', 'ProductController@update')->name('productos.update');
```

De ahí que el error sea "Método no permitido".

---

Laravel sugiere utilizar PUT / PATCH para las ediciones, por lo cual deberías modificar la ruta:

```
Route::put('/admin/products/{id}', 'ProductController@update')->name('productos.update');
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias me ayudo mucho, saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Revisando el codigo debes mejorar esto

Utilizas PUT en el formulario:

```
{!!Form::model($RenombradoBuscarVista, ['method' => 'PUT', 'action' => ['ProductController@update',$RenombradoBuscarVista->id]]) !!}
```

La ruta esta esperando un POST:

```
Route::post('/admin/products/{id}', 'ProductController@update')->name('productos.update');
```

De ahí que el error sea "Método no permitido".

sustituyela por

```
Route::put('/admin/products/{id}', 'ProductController@update')->name('productos.update');
```

Ademas en la controller realizas esta busqueda

```
$Producto = Producto::find($idCategoria );
```

y supongo que la categoria se un campo del producto y no su llave primaria por lo que deberias utilizar esta linea:

```
$Producto = Producto::where('category_id', $idCategoria)->get();
```

Lo mismo aplicalo a la hora de salvar la imagen

esta de esta forma:

```
$Imagen = ProductImage::find($idProducto);
$Imagen->product_id = $idProducto;
$Imagen->save();
```

Quedaria mejor si:

```
$Imagen = ProductImage::where('product_id',$idProducto)->get();
$Imagen->product_id = $idProducto;
$Imagen->save();
```

Comment: 1. La solución planteada es igual a la otra respuesta, 2. Las supuestas mejoras planteadas son incorrectas. -1

Answer (score 0):

A veces pasa que refrescas directamente la URL donde tienes que recibir el post , y por lo que sea , sesión caducada o simplemente que introduces directamente la URL sin haber pasado antes por el formulario y te da ese error, llegando a esa url desde donde se rellenan los datos , en este caso solucionaría el error...
Por cierto si alguien sabe como detectar esto que nos ilumine con el código...

Comment: Esto mas que una respuesta, sirve como comentario.