# como puedo hacer que mis campos sean requeridos en laravel y no se envien si estan vacios

Tags: laravel, formularios

probe colocandole el required pero no me funciona

```
    <html>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalRegisterForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Gerencia</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body mx-6">
                {{Form::open(array( 'url'=>'#','id'=>'formulario','method'=>'post'))}}
                <h1>Registrar<span class="badge badge-secondary">Gerencias</span></h1>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('codigo', 'Codigo:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        {!! Form::text('codigo', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control','maxlength'=>'2', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el Codigo','required'=> 'true']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('ga', 'Gerencia administrativa:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        {!! Form::text('ga', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre dela Gerencia']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>

                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">

                <span  class="btn btn-success" onclick="submit()" id="enviar">GUARDAR</span>

                {{--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="submit(e)" id="enviar">GUARDAR</button>--}}




            </div>
            {{Form::close()}}
            <div id="resultado"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>




<script>
    function submit () {
           // e.preventDefault();

        $.ajaxSetup({

            header:$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        });

        $('#enviar').attr("disabled","disabled");
        var url = 'gerencia.crear';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $('#formulario').serialize(),
            dataType:'html',

            success: function (data) {
                var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if ((obj.estado=='ok')){
                    alert(obj.mensaje);
                    window.location="{{ route('gerencia_inicio') }}"

                } else{
                    alert(obj.mensaje);
                    $('#enviar').removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: cuando renderiza el `html` el navegador verificas que este el `required`? prueba tambien agregando un valor, algo así `'required' => 'required'`

Comment: no lo esta verificando y si quito el value=null entonces me tira un error

Comment: No se si me hice entender, lo que digo es que cuando inspeccionas el código directamente en el navegador, ves el required en el input?

Comment: si me sale required='' ''

Comment: ya vi cual es el error, estas usando un `span` como boton, lo ideal sería que usaras un `button`. Algo asi: `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="submit()" id="enviar">GUARDAR</button>`, espero te sirva

Comment: bueno es que estoy utilizando ajax para guardar ese registro

Comment: No importa, por que un formulario sin un `submit` como tal no va a funcionar correctamente, lo que puedes hacer es poner en el evento de javascript un `preventDefault();` para validar

Comment: lo intente ahorita y si ese es  el problema pero ahora me tira un errror  Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message

Comment: ahi modifique y coloque mi ajax para ver si me das una idea como realizar el preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se podría hacer

```
<html>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalRegisterForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Gerencia</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body mx-6">
                {{Form::open(array( 'url'=>'#','id'=>'formulario','method'=>'post'))}}
                <h1>Registrar<span class="badge badge-secondary">Gerencias</span></h1>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('codigo', 'Codigo:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        {!! Form::text('codigo', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control','maxlength'=>'2', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el Codigo','required']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('ga', 'Gerencia administrativa:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        {!! Form::text('ga', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre dela Gerencia','required']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>

                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="submit(e)" id="enviar">GUARDAR</button>
            </div>
            {{Form::close()}}
            <div id="resultado"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>




<script>
    function submit (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // evita que se haga el submit  del formulario
        $.ajaxSetup({
            header:$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        });

        $('#enviar').attr("disabled","disabled");
        var url = 'gerencia.crear';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $('#formulario').serialize(),
            dataType:'html',
            success: function (data) {
                var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if ((obj.estado=='ok')){
                    alert(obj.mensaje);
                    window.location="{{ route('gerencia_inicio') }}"
                } else{
                    alert(obj.mensaje);
                    $('#enviar').removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Intenta con esto, ya que no puedo ver bien como es el funcionamiento real

Comment: no me esta funcionando me tira el mismo error

Comment: ya ese error es por otra cosa, cheka [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150721/error-en-laravel-al-hacer-post-symfony-component-httpkernel-exception-me),  te puede ayudar a solucionarlo

Comment: creo que tengo que hacerlo de una manera diferente por que la ruta si me la encuentra si lo realizo de la otra forma el problema es cuando utilizo un button tipo submit con ajax que me tira el error

Comment: Pero es que no puede ser ese el error, es el archivo php donde haces el ajax, o ya tendrías que postear bien todo el código y analizarlo mejor

Comment: ahorita coloque todo el codigo del php